# Sampling from a distribution with a margin of error

Tags: distributions, sampling, random-variable

A survey of a population is taken using sampling. It is determined that 70% prefer option A and 30% prefer option B with a margin of error being 5%.

Normally when simulating the process with the above denoted stats and without using the margin of error, one simply samples a random uniform distribution say between [1,100] as X and resolves that the ith outcome is option A if X is less than 70 otherwise option B

**Question:**
How would one go about modifying the above process to take into account (aka incorporate) the 5% margin of error?

Comment: What do you mean by 'a 5% margin of error'? How did you get it? Answering that will help you get an answer on how to simulate the situation.

Comment: @iwi: Margin of error as described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error#Definition